# Force Synchronous function execution with callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have *one* opportunity to manipulate the DOM of my page *before* it's styled, rendered and shown to the user. 
Obviously, I'd love to do all the dynamic fun stuff within this window as DOM manipulations are very expensive after the page as rendered.  Since this is primarily targeted at mobile devices, this optimization is valuable to me.

Here's a basic overview / timeline:

```
function CalledBeforePageRendered(){
    DoAsyncDataBaseWorkWithCallBack(AsyncDataBaseCallBack);
    DoLocalizationsAndOtherSYNCRONOUSActions();
}


function AsyncDataBaseCallBack(results){
    // code that processes the results element
    // code that manipulates the DOM *before* it's styled.
}
```

The problem is that `DoAsyncDataBaseWorkWithCallBack` and `DoLocalizationsAndOtherSYNCRONOUSActions`
finish quickly and then `CalledBeforePageRendered` returns and subsequent styling is applied.

After the styling is applied, the page is shown to the user... and then `AsyncDataBaseCallBack` gets called
which then applies div tags and other DOM modifications.  Only, I needed these modifications to take place before stylization

Is there any way I can make '`CalledBeforePageRendered`' wait for '`AsyncDataBaseCallBack`' to finish before returning?  I know that a closure would usually work here, but I do not know how to make a closure work with a callback that is defined outside of the `CalledBeforePageRendered` function.

Comment: why are you doing the DataBaseWork asynchronously? if all your work (Db&Dom) has to be synched at the end, why not just send the data and the html constructed from the server?

Comment: When you say 'subsequent styling is applied', do you mean more JS or just the rest of the page rendering stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to perform a synchronous JavaScript XmlHttpRequest (XHR) call - that's very possible, but assuming your trying to manipulate the DOM on the client side before the page is rendered - why don't you do that on the server side (since it's generating the HTML in the first place).  If you can't I highly recommend you don't perform a synchronous JavaScript XHR to update the page before it's rendered.  Doing so will lock up the browser window while the XHR is running which can not only add significant latency to page loading - it also frustrates end users (since they experience what appears to be a hard 'lock').  Manipulating the DOM before it's rendered isn't *that* costly.  It's better to return the HTML you want in the first place though - instead of loading more after the page has loaded.

Again - I'd just like to emphasize - try to do this work on the server side (not client).  If you can't and need to perform this as a secondary call - add a loading image and let XHR's run asynchronously like most JavaScript libraries pretty much enforce anyways.  If I am misunderstanding your goals, please let me know.

Comment: I thought about doing it that way, but the server side API's that i have were - how to put this nicely - not designed by people with experience building API's.


The reason i don't want to update the DOM after it's been displayed is that i am using a framework that expects HTML of a certain format, then stylizes that HTML based on the device.  Inserting known working HTML after the page has been stylized does not have desired results as the framework has already parsed the HTML and moddified the DOM.

The data i need to display is already stored on the device in a SQLIte database.

Comment: I guess that i can reverse engineer the DOM modifications that the framework uses to manually create my own HTML that will work with the framework's styling.

Comment: Are you tied to this framework?  What technology?  There are many ways to skin a cat here.